# Multiplication of men on earth

Tags: genesis

In genesis 4 our ancestors had only two kids Abel and Cain. Abel was killed. How to explain multiplication of world population  then?

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to give you an answer without giving my opinion. You may want to read Genesis 5, specifically verses 3-5:

> Genesis 5:3–5 (LEB): **3** And when Adam had lived one hundred and thirty years, he fathered a child in his likeness, according to his image. And he called his name Seth. **4** And the days of Adam after he fathered Seth were eight hundred years. *And he fathered sons and daughters.* [italics added for emphasis] **5** And all the days of Adam which he lived were nine hundred and thirty years, and he died.

If you happen to read the text more "literally" (for lack of a better word), then this may answer your question: Adam had more children in addition to Cain, Abel and Seth.

Comment: I'm very happy you helped me. Your answer is perfect. A group of ungodly people were insulating believers to follow foreign religion with the  bible full of lies and quoted this passage. Happy you give a biblical quotation to give the correct answer. I'm quite satisfied.  Blessings

Comment: Glad I could help! God bless.